# Custom Metadata Query Returning Wrong Values

Tags: custom-metadata

I have a single record under a Custom Metadata Object.  The object has a checkbox field, and in this one record I have that box checked to TRUE.

However, when I query the Custom Metadata Object, the query result shows that the field is FALSE.

Here's my setup, the only record in this object and it has the checkbox checked:

[image: This is the single custom metadata record I have. Note the checkbox is checked.]

And then here's the result when I query this object:
[image: SOQL Query Result for the above record.]

As you can see it's returning false for the field that I have set to true.  The Record is set to "Protected Component = false", and the Object itself is set to Public, and the checkbox field is set to "Subscriber Editable".

I'm working in a packaging org trying to get this to work for a managed package.  Any idea why it's returning the wrong value?

Comment: I also tried this in dev org. You are correct I am not able to get its value as true. I think here you need to raise case with salesforce. Please   update same here if you get anything from salesforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is a bug/known issue found here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bS6AAI

The solution is to shorten the field's API name, which worked for me in this instance.